# Defining loss function in Keras as element wise multiplication with negation of every second element

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to define my own cost function in Keras running on top of Tensorflow. While having `y_true = [a0, a1, a2, a3, ..., an]` and `y_pred = [b0, b1, b2, b3, ..., bn]` as ground truth and predictions, respectively, I want to define the cost function as: `cost = a0*b0 - a1*b1 + a2*b2 - a3*b3 + ...`.

In short, I want to define something like this:

```
def my_cost(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.multiply(y_true, y_pred)
```

but every second element has to be negated. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the following `cost_function` to work; in essence, we make a trick and select the odd and even indices; we multiply only the `y_true` and `y_pred` counterparts considering their oddity.

Then we use the `tf.math.reduce_sum()` in order to actually compute the sum for the cost; you can also use `tf.math.subtract(first_sum,second_sum)` but for simplicity sake I kept the '`-`'.

```
def my_cost(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_even = y_true[::2]
    y_true_odd = y_true[1::2]

    y_pred_even = y_pred[::2]
    y_pred_odd = y_pred[1::2]

    result = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(y_true_even,y_pred_even)) - tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(y_true_odd,y_pred_odd)) 
    return result
```